# Linux software RAID 10 array, failed drive, resize file system and migrate to a 3 drive RAID 1?

Tags: centos, software-raid, mdadm, raid10

I have a software RAID 10 array which I recently noticed went into a degraded state. The OS is CentOS 5.8.

It has 4x 500GB drives in 3 different arrays:
/dev/md0 is RAID 1 and mounted to /boot (200MB ext3)
/dev/md1 is RAID 10 and is swap (4GB swap)
/dev/md2 is RAID 10 and is the main system and data device (895GB ext3)

One of the drives has failed but only /dev/md2 (main system and data array) is degraded.
Here's the full mdadm and /proc/mdstat output... http://pastebin.com/VL0uYdU9

The problem seems to be failed sectors on one of the drives...

```
Dec  9 04:25:37 hostname smartd[3199]: Device: /dev/sdb, 1 Currently unreadable (pending) sectors
Dec  9 04:25:37 hostname smartd[3199]: Device: /dev/sdb, 1 Offline uncorrectable sectors
```

Replacing the drive ASAP is the ideal option. However I won't have physical access to the server for the next few weeks. I have backups going to another device on the network anyway so we should be covered if another drive goes (the mirror of the already failed drive).

Is there a way I can resize the file system of /dev/md2 down to under 500GB, so I can then migrate the degraded RAID 10 to a 3 drive RAID 1 array?
And can this be attempted online (full, verified, backups being made of course)?
I don't have access to the server for loading a recovery CD.

Answer (score 1):

The linux software `RAID 10` does not support any form of reshaping.  Your only option to change it is, backup, to take it offline, build a new volume, and restore your data.

Comment: Is there a way to remove another drive from the RAID 10 array, leaving only 2 drives. Removing the correct drive so the system/data is still intact. Then re-partition/re-format that drive as a solo drive and image the system and data across. Set it as the boot drive and restart. Then take the 2 remaining drives in the RAID 10, delete that array and build into a RAID 1 mirror, copy the data back over to that, set it as the boot array. Reboot. Then add that 3rd solo drive as the 3rd drive in the RAID 1 mirror?

Comment: I guess, that might be theoretically possible, maybe, but I would never try it.  If you are really interested in trying that, then I would suggest you create a virtual machine that mimics your production environment exactly, and then see if you can make it work.